# Stream_get_content not working for the second time?

Tags: php, streaming

I am working with a stream_get_content the first time. Everything seems ok until i tried to read the content from the stream for the second time.

if my value that pass to the stream_get_content is repeating  , return empty value !?

but if my value isn't repeating everything is good!!!!

```
public function makeAvatar($value)
{
    $file_result = "data:image/gif;base64,";
    $file_result .= base64_encode(stream_get_contents($value));
    return $file_result;
}
```

Comment: I suppose, when you invoke stream_get_contents(), it reads from the stream until it reaches EOF, then the handle (here $value) is closed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can to use [rewind()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rewind.php) to reset the pointer to the beginning of the stream.